# internet memory

Tags: memory, internet, cookies, tracking

How do I delete the cookies (I think that is what it is called) that track the internet use so that it remembers the most common phrases or searches entered into the window and pops up with a list?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to clear **Auto-complete Form History**.
Simply, use [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) for that. It supports almost all major web browsers.